# angularjs form validation shows success on page load with empty form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller, sweetalert

I have the following form, but some field are showing the success messages below the box on page load, without even touching the form.
What is the problem?

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('ValidationCtrl', ["$scope", "$state", "$timeout", "SweetAlert","$location", "firebase", "$translate","$http", "$rootScope", "flowFactory",
    function ($scope, $state, $timeout, SweetAlert, $location, firebase, $translate, $http, $rootScope, flowFactory) {

        $scope.master = $scope.myModel;
        $scope.form = {

            submit: function (form) {
                var firstError = null;
                if (form.$invalid) {
                    var field = null, firstError = null;
                    for (field in form) {
                        if (field[0] != '$') {
                            if (firstError === null && !form[field].$valid) {
                                firstError = form[field].$name;
                            }
                            if (form[field].$pristine) {
                                form[field].$dirty = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    angular.element('.ng-invalid[name=' + firstError + ']').focus();
                    SweetAlert.swal("The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors!", "Errors are marked with a red, dashed border!", "error");
                    return;

                } else {
                    SweetAlert.swal("Good job!", "Your form is ready to be submitted!", "success");
                    //your code for submit
                }

            },
            reset: function (form) {

                $scope.myModel = angular.copy($scope.master);
                form.$setPristine(true);

            }
        };

}]);
```

and here is the field that shows the success text on page load on empty form:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.keyword.$dirty && Form.keyword.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.keyword.$valid}" >
    <label class="control-label" translate="list.keyword">
        Keyword<span class="symbol required"></span>
    </label>
    <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="true" ng-model="myModel.keyword" theme="bootstrap" name="keyword"  title="Choose a keyword">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter the keywords...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="r in list.keylist | filter:$select.search">
            {{r}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.keyword.$dirty && Form.keyword.$error.required">Keyword is required.</span>
    <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.keyword.$dirty && Form.keyword.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
    <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.keyword.$valid">Correct!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try with ng-show instead of ng-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using required and minlength attributes in your ui-select. Something like following.

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="true" ng-model="myModel.keyword" theme="bootstrap" name="keyword"  title="Choose a keyword" required minlength="6">
```

There is a known bug here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/258